# How can I determine what is downloading per Conky?

Tags: networking

For the past several minutes, Conky has indicated that something has been downloading something.  I'm not running any programs that would account for that, the box isn't running anything other than Firefox for me to type this in.  I've noticed this happening before.

How can I tell what/why something is being downloaded?

Edit: Box is Ubuntu 22.04.1

Okay, now I'm worried - rebooted the box, ran a sudo netstat -p and saved the output.  Walked away and came back about an hour later and it was downloading again.  Ran another sudo netstat -p and saved that output.  Another hour later and the downloading has stopped.  What could be going on?  There's no notification of an update ready to install.

Comment: `netstat -p` might contain a clue. It won't tell you _what_ is being downloaded, but it may help you figure out which process it is. Also (if you haven't yet), have you tried closing Firefox and/or simply rebooting the machine...?

Comment: @cocomac Of course, just now it stopped, but it happens with some regularity so I'll try next time I see it.  Just to be sure, I did close Firefox after posting the question, and the download did continue...  Rebooting does stop it... for a while.  Oh!  It just started again - thanks

Comment: My first guess would be an automatic update (apt does this for some packages, Snap does it for all snaps).

Comment: @cocomac Most everything else in the netstat -p output was zeros, except this:
tcp     2208      0 asrock:38320            10.0.0.11:netbios-ssn   ESTABLISHED 5334/gvfsd-smb-brow 

So this says that 10.0.0.11 on my LAN is the culprit?  That's a Raspberry Pi running Kodi. ??  That box shouldn't be downloading anything from this box.

Comment: We currently don't even know your OS/release or have any product details. We have no idea what packages you've installed, what extensions you've added (`firefox` or browser can have permissions altered when extensions are loaded that allow for background processes to run etc)....  Please provide some product details.

Comment: @cocomac - I unplugged all three of my Pi's (wasn't sure which was which) but the downloading is still pumping strong

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 21.04.01, Firefox 103.0.2, a WebRTC blocker is the only extention added.  I just exited Firefox and killed one still running and the downloading continued

Comment: @guiverc - sorry, that was a typo.  The box is 22.04.1

Comment: @LarryM please [edit] your question to give us relevant information - comments can get lost...